# JQuery: Populate textarea with ajax response

Tags: jquery, populate

I have a dynamically created dropdown list in a form in which I can select newsletters from my MySQL Database. The itention is that when I select a newsletter the content from the the database gets inserted in a textarea.

The dropdown list is this:

```
<?php
    echo "<select id=\"NieuwsbriefSelect\" name=\"show\">"; 
    echo "<option size =30 selected>Select</option>";
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql_result)) 
    { 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) 
    { 
    echo "<option value=\"$row[Titel]\">$row[Titel]</option>"; 
    } 

    } 
    else {
    echo "<option>No Names Present</option>";  
    } 
?>
```

The jquery is this:

```
<script>
// variable to hold request
var request;
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#NieuwsbriefSelect').change(function() { 
//send Ajax call to get new contents 
var selected_text = $(this).val(); 
// setup some local variables 
var $form = $("#myForm"); 
// let's select and cache all the fields 
var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea"); 
// serialize the data in the form 
var serializedData = $form.serialize(); 

alert(serializedData); 

// fire off the request to /get_my_contents.php 
request = $.ajax({ 
url: "/get_my_contents.php", 
type: "GET", 
data: serializedData 
}); 

alert("ajax call done"); 

// callback handler that will be called on success 
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
//populate the TextArea 
alert(response); 
$("textarea[name='content']").html(response); 
}); 



});

});
</script>
```

The get_my_contents.php:

```
<?php 
$title = $_REQUEST["show"]; 
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root'); 
mysql_select_db('NAW') or die (mysql_error()); 
$strSQL = "SELECT Content from NAW.Mail where Titel = '$title' "; 
$sql_result = mysql_query($strSQL); 

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result); 

print urldecode($row["Content"]); 
?>
```

So what it should do is add the response into the textarea. The problem however is that the ajax request doesn't seem to do anything. When I run this and select a newsletter from the dropdown list I will get the first 2 alerts but after that it does nothing. I will also mention that I have basicly no experience with Jquery but someone else suggested that I should use this and helped me to get it like the current state. If anyone can see what is wrong or suggest another way it would be great!

***NOTE:***
I know I shouldn't be using mysql_* and I will be changing to PDO later on!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if this is an issue, but i would rewrite code like this:

```
request = $.ajax({ 
url: "/get_my_contents.php", 
type: "GET", 
data: serializedData
success: function(data)
    {
    //populate the TextArea 
    alert(data);
    $("textarea[name='content']").html(data); 
    }
});
```

Comment: If I use this it will not even display the other alerts anymore.

Comment: Have you checked, what you get from MySQL query?

Comment: Yes, the MySQL Query on get_my_contents.php works fine and will get the right content.

Comment: try writing "exit;" after "print urldecode($row["Content"]);"

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTextareaVal = $('#message-textarea').val();

$.ajax({                                       
      type: "GET",
      url: "myPhpFile.php",           
      data: "text=" + myTextareaVal,           
      cache: false,
      dataType: "html",           
      success: function(data) {   
            $('.modal_content').find('.message:last').before(data);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

'data' probably has line breaks

```
$("textarea[name='content']").html(data);
```

=

```
$("textarea[name='content']").html('line number1
line number2

line number3 with a previous blank line');
```

And line breaks result in an error in js

You just have to fix line breaks.